# Квалификация знаний

Tags: работа

Мне 21 год, я более чем начинающий программист, имеющий не достаточно хорошего опыта. Были проекты и на Qt(C++) и на Java, Asp.net, но всё на определённо недостаточном уровне. Умение написание алгоритмов очень даже неплохое, достаточно быстро нахожу решение задачи, но технических знаний мало, всегда приходится копаться в инфо ресурсах. На данный момент работаю в компании и знаю, что с опытом всё будет налаживаться, но я не могу выбрать направление. Не знаю за какую спецификацию сначала взяться, чтобы улучшить её до профессионального уровня. Одно желание быть одним из лучших в своей стране (Азербайджан). За счёт компании меня хотят направить на курсы для сертификации, на моё усмотрение. Помогите советами, пожалуйста. С чего начать?

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю вам надо поменять страну.

Аргументирую: недостаточно иметь способности, необходима еще соответствующее окружение, атмосфера, дух соперничества и сотрудничества. Нужна критическая масса, как я понимаю этого нет в Азербайджане и может быть никогда и не будет - я что-то не слышал о хороших прогерах из Азербайджана. Переезжайте в нерезиновую, Калифорнию или Киев, Минск и проч. - пара лет и вы получите сполна то о чем вы мечтаете.

**P.S.** 21 это уже много - оч. много...

Comment: Чтобы переехать в Калифорнию и найти там работу программистом, уже нужно иметь хорошие знания и умения?
21 много для чего? Мне было далеко не 21 когда занялся программированием. И ничего. Достиг кое-чего. Это наверное зависит от желания, мотивации и способностей в большей степени!

Comment: солидарен с @zhenyab. Начинать никогда не поздно. Главное - желание и стремление к цели.

Comment: Тогда начинайте с стран поближе, наверное?

Comment: В каждой стране есть хорошие программисты. Просто будет сложнее найти таковых и устроится в адекватную фирму. Тут уже скорее вопрос личных качеств топик-стартера.

Comment: >21 это уже много - оч. много

это очень много разве что для начала карьеры футболиста или фотомодели, но для порграммиста - это самое начало. Многие даже позже начинают (скажем, после института и армии)

Comment: @Sharbag вы видимо не поняли мессидж моего ответа или скорее я не совсем верно его изложил. Проблема не в способностях, талантах индивида, а в его окружении. Если есть рядом люди которые могут учить у которых он может учиться значит он будет расти. А если нет - то будь ты хоть семи пядей во лбу - останешься митрофаном. А 21 много или мало - все тут субъективно. Допускаю, что я неправ.

Answer (score 2):

Могу сказать от себя, что столкнулся с той же проблемой, но уже продвинулся в решении этого вопроса. Для того что бы понять в какую сторону лучше развиваться, надо поработать над реальным проектом в том или ином языке.

Я 9 месяцев поработал на c# и понял, что скорее это не моё, ибо совместимость с другими операционными системами находится на достаточно низком уровне. Ниже чем я ожидал. Сам с# по себе очень даже сэкси и обладает многими интересными возможностямя, но он привязан к майкрософту...

В Qt и C++, там всё интересно. Портабельность лучше, язык распространненый, но вот беда, на нем почти не пишут enterprise приложений или очень мало(как я понял, по крайней мере). Как следствие приложения на нем создаются весьма специфичные. Да и c++ всё таки несколько сложнее чем C#/Java. Цикл разработки приложений на с++ скорее всего дольше чем у двух других языков --> экономически не так рентабельно для фирм.

Java... Тут я сказать пока что ничего не могу. Еще пока что ничего особо большого на Java не писал. Но если верить данному индексу: http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html то ява на данный момент самый распространненый язык. А тут уже другие проблемы - выше конкуренция. А еще в последнее время oracle делают много косяков и авторитетность явы падает.

P.S. IMHO

Comment: @Sharbag, а mono не пробовали?

Comment: Моно всё равно поддерживает только старые версии .NET и то не без проблем. Я имел опыт с Silverlight'ом, а с ним на линуксе вообще всё плохо. Актуальная версия 5, а на mono едва-едва 3я поддерживается. Конечно, это вопрос времени/запросов, но всё же mono не на том уровне что бы говорить, что он хорош как ява. Да и IDE под С# для других ОСей не таки хорошие как VisualStudio

Comment: Только старые версии? Вы шутите? В [официальной документации](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility) написано, что

* .NET 4.0 — реализовано всё, кроме WPF
* .NET 4.5 — реализовано всё, кроме WPF и Async для MVC 4/ASP.NET 4.5.

---
Silverlight объявлен deprecated самой Microsoft.

Comment: Оу! Позитив! Я последний раз делал разведку на эти темы где-то в январе. То ли на устаревшую информацию натыкался, то ли доделали. Когда я смотрел, поддерживался только .NET 3.5. 
Я еще с WCF работал, но в моно он тоже не так хорошо поддерживается. Как снова скажу, работа в mono это не равно работа с вин-.net.

Comment: К тому же, на мой взгляд, C# получает большой плюс за счет WPF, а в Mono его нет вообще.

Comment: @Sharbag: да, WPF — крутая вещь. Для Mono [документация](http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits), судя по всему, рекомендует Gtk#.

Comment: Да я в курсе GTK, но на столько же он мощен как и WPF или это скорее костыль?

Comment: @Sharbag, а Вам в самом деле интересно возиться с рисованием portable окошек?

Comment: @Sharbag а есть рядом люди у которых можно учиться? Или вы сами все себе пробиваете?

Comment: @Sharbag: насчёт GTK не знаю, я подвиндист. Что скажут эксперты?